# Infrared divergency in the correction to the electron vertex Function in QED/ Question to Schwartz "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, integration

I'm currently studying Mathew Schwartz's "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model". In the chapter on Infrared divergences (Page 359 (7th edition, hard cover))
he calculates the infrared divergent correction to the electron vertex.

[image: This is the page I'm referring to]

I tried to confirm equation (20.17) but I have no idea how to perform the integral. That is, I managed to do the y-integration but then I get to something, I don't know how to integrate and also don't know how to expand in the photon mass. I would really like to understand how the result emerges, because this is the first time we see a Sudakov double Logarithm in the book and I want to see, how it emerges.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: fwiw I have written in the margin next to this equation in  my Schwartz book that the "integral is not trivial, see my notes on P&S". I will dig these out....

Comment: P&S don't evaluate this explicitly, but they look at the behaviour near the divergence. Which occurs near $x \approx 0$ and $y \approx 0$. They then deduce the appearance of the Sudakov double logarithm from there. It might be worthwhile you having a look at that on p199.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At least I was now able to derive the divergent part. I guess I'll be content with it, in practice one would probably use numerical methods anyway.
Btw., I checked out your notes and they are amazing! Tanks a lot for making them available.

Comment: You’re welcome ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually possible to do the integral explicitly. To do so, it's convenient to decouple the x- and y-integration. Thus introduce $ \tilde{x}=1-x$ and $y= \tilde{x} \tilde{y}$ and define $r \equiv \frac{m^2_{\gamma}}{-Q^2}$. The integral reads now (dropping the tildes)
$$ \int_0^1 dx \frac{-x}{1-x-r} \int_0^1 dy \frac{1-x \; y}{y+\frac{r}{1-x-r}}$$. Doing the y integration gives $$ \frac{a x(x-(1+a x)\log\left( 1+ \frac{1}{a}\right))}{r}$$, where we abbreviated $a \equiv \frac{r}{1-x-r}$. Now the x integration can be done and the zeroth order term in $r$ gives equation (20.17). The Sudakov double logarithm appears when expanding the dilogarithm $$ \text{Li}_2\left(1-\frac{1}{r} \right) = -\frac{\log^2(r)}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{6} +\mathcal{O}(r).$$